# Quarkus: Named datasources, multitenancy and persistence units

Tags: database, api, hibernate, microservices, quarkus

I have a project with 2 datasources, a primary and a fallback datasource. I have added these to applications.properties and I am using the DATABASE multitenancy approach. I have a custom TenantResolver implementation that changes the active tenant, and the only entities I have defined are in an external module.

The issue is simply this: saving to both of my datasources works just fine, however in order to get the app to start I have to include a dummy datasource:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=dummy
```

in the properties file. Otherwise I get the error:
The default datasource is not configured but the persistence unit '' uses it.
The actual datasources I'm using are defined like so:

```
quarkus.datasource.primary.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://...
quarkus.datasource.secondary.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://...
```

and saving to them works just fine.

So the question is: how should i configure my application so I don't have to include this dummy datasource to avoid the persistence unit error?

Here is the entire properties file:

```
# Enable DATABASE approach
quarkus.hibernate-orm.multitenant=DATABASE

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=dummy

# Primary tenant
quarkus.datasource.primary.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.primary.username=reportinguser
quarkus.datasource.primary.password=pw123
quarkus.datasource.primary.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reportingdb1

# Secondary tenant
quarkus.datasource.secondary.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.secondary.username=reportinguser2
quarkus.datasource.secondary.password=password
quarkus.datasource.secondary.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reportingdb1
```

Comment: Could you add your whole application.properties? Credentials excluded :)

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet 

`# Enable DATABASE approach
quarkus.hibernate-orm.multitenant=DATABASE

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=dummy

# Primary tenant
quarkus.datasource.primary.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.primary.username=reportinguser
quarkus.datasource.primary.password=pw123
quarkus.datasource.primary.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reportingdb1

# Secondary tenant
quarkus.datasource.secondary.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.secondary.username=reportinguser2
quarkus.datasource.secondary.password=password`

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue like yours. you can add line below to specify the default data source
quarkus.hibernate-orm.datasource=primary